# function return on javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am reading a book about javascript and I came across this syntax

this is a function

```
function unwantedTextEvent(){
  return (navigator.vendor == 'Apple Computer, Inc.' && (event.target == event.relatedTarget.parentNode
  || (event.eventPhase == 3 && event.target.parentNode == event.relatedTarget)));
};
```

and then inside another function , the author is doing just this

```
attachEventListener(li, 'mouseover', function(e){
 if (unwantedTextEvent()) { return; }
 clearTimeout(closetime);
 if (branch == li) { branch = null; }
 //and so on
```

Now, I am ashamed to admit that I have never seen that syntax again :

```
 if (unwantedTextEvent()) { return; }
```

and I dont have a clue what it does. Can anybody please explain to me? What does this syntax does in general?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It just calls the function and uses the returned value in the if condition.

Comment: Could you clarify which part of that code is confusing you? In general, the way to understand any code is to break it down into its constituent parts. If you understand what each piece does, the overall meaning should become clear.

Comment: It calls unwantedTextEvent() function and if return from this function is false then control returned from complete function(that anonymous function in attachEventListenter).

Comment: @Nish You're just repeating what all the answers say, aren't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That syntax calls a function called `unwantedTextEvent()`. If that function returns an affirmative Boolean value, then the callback `function(e)` inside of `attachEventListener` is returned.

It simply stops executing in the callback function.

Comment: So if `unwantedTextEvent()` returns true, `function(e)` keeps executing and if `unwantedTextEvent()` returns false, `function(e)` stops? And code continues after the `function(e)`?

Comment: @user2860857 you have it flipped. If the condition is `true`(i.e. when `unwantedTextEvent()` is `true`), then `function(e)` returns. If it does not meet the condition, it goes on to check the rest of the function until it ends or returns due to another condition being met later.

Comment: OK, so look at this `http://jsfiddle.net/slevin/fUeFk/12/`. If I put `a>4` (true), then only ping is alerted (function returns- gets executed untill it meets the if condition). If I put `a<4` (false) then the whole function is executed. I think, now I got it...

Comment: @user2860857 there ya go :). `Javascript` has some cramped syntax that can be confusing at first.

Comment: OK, got it. Thanks. Funny thing, your answer confused my at first, but now, turns out its the most well-written. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `unwantedTextEvent()` is just a big condition. If that condition is true, it stop running the function

The code after a return is never run.

It is the same as doing :

```
if (!unwantedTextEvent()) {
    clearTimeout(closetime);
    if (branch == li) { branch = null; }
    //and so on
}
```

Comment: So, if I got it right : if `unwantedTextEvent()` returns true, `function(e)` is not executed, and if it returns false, `function(e)` is executed? How can I edit the code to do like `if returns false`? Like `if (unwantedTextEvent()) { !return; }`

Comment: @user2860857 you got it. If you want the other way around, you'd have to negate the if : `if (!unwantedTextEvent()) { return; }`. See the band inside the if?

Comment: OK thanks. In general if its true, the function exits, if it is false the function continues. Am I right? Based on bwtrent's answer and this `http://jsfiddle.net/slevin/fUeFk/12/`

Comment: @user2860857 exactly!

Answer (score 0):

Return exits the function immediately. That syntax exits without returning a value.

Answer (score 0):

It's an ordinary `if` statement. The general form of `if` is:

```
if (<test expression>) {
    <code to execute>
}
```

optionally followed by an `else` clause (but your example doesn't have this).

In this case, `<test expression>` is a call to the function `unwantedTextEvent`. If it returns a true value, the `<code to execute>` is executed, and the function returns. Otherwise, it continues with the rest of the function.

Comment: That's not what the OP is asking.

Comment: @Scimonster - Looks like exactly what the OP is asking for ?

Comment: I'm usually pretty good at reading between the lines to figure out what people are asking, but I admit I'm not really sure which part of the code confused him.

Comment: It looked to me that he was confused about the `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

the `return;` statement simply exits out of the function passed into the attachEvenListener.  i.e. the anonymous function.